# Button is behind divs and co.. z-index pointless?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have the "Kontakt" button in the right cornor at the front. So, this button is supposed to be above everything else. I already set the z-index to `z-index: 99999999999 !important;` but it doens't effect anything...

On desktop the button is above everything except the footer at the bottom. On mobile its a disaster... Its behind everything... Try yourself..

But why and how can I fix that? - Here the site: https://j-trier.de

Code:

```
<button onClick="location.href='#kontakt'" type="button" id="kontakt_button" class="cl-popup-trigger type_btn cl-btn">Kontakt</button>
```

Greetings

Comment: Hi user7422244, please put the minimal amount of relevant code needed to reproduce the problem **in the post itself** - don't just link to your website, which will change over time, making this post useless to people who find it in the future and can't reference your original code. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: post the relevant code. In general: "Meine Leistungen" should be what you offer not asking 15 questions and change the opacity for the modals its quite hard to read the text inside the box when you click on "weiterlesen". Just a tip :)

Comment: And just move the button `<button onclick="location.href='#kontakt'" type="button" id="kontakt_button" class="cl-popup-trigger type_btn cl-btn">Kontakt</button>` to just before the closing body tag (`</body>`)

Comment: I added the code above, sorry guys..

Comment: Why should I move it to the end of the `</body>` tag? - I just want to understand the logic of it

Comment: be sure to `@` me or I won't get a notification of messages. If I'm remembering correctly, it was an issue with z-index on one of the parents. But I just went to your site and am not seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put your button code direct inside of body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have used Z-index property in right way. But there is a problem in CSS  file “us-base.min.css” .  On class  “l-canvas class” there is a property “overflow: hidden”  which is making it invisible. So remove this property. If you want to use it so use it in such way ”overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible; 
Happy  Coding!